# столкнулся с проблемой с приказом графика на python

Tags: python, plotly

изучаю самостоятельно из книге и не понимаю в чем ошибаюсь но график не хочет выстроить..

```
import requests

from plotly.graph_objs import Bar
from plotly import offline

# создание вызова API и сохранение ответа
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

# обработка результатов
response_dict = r.json()

repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

repo_names, stars = [], []

for repo_dict in repo_dicts:

    repo_names.append(repo_dict['name'])

    stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])

# построенная визуализация
data = [{
    'type': 'bar',
    'x': 'repo_names',
    'y': 'stars',
}]


my_layout = {

    'title': "Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub",

    'xaxis': {'title': 'Repository'},

    'ysxis': {'title': 'Stars'},
}

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}

offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html')
```

Comment: Ошибка есть? Какая?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python_work\study\XVII API\python_repos_visual.py", line 34, in <module>
    offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html')                                                                    ...                                                                                                                                         ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'x' property of bar
 Received value: 'repo_names' The 'x' property is an array that may be specified as a tuple,list, numpy array, or pandas Series

Comment: offline.plot(fig, filename='python_repos.html') говорить что проблема в этой строке из-за присвоенного значения к X и  Y

Comment: помоги пожалуйста @Эникейщик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замени

```
data = [{
    'type': 'bar',
    'x': 'repo_names',
    'y': 'stars',
}]
```

на

```
data = [{
    'type': 'bar',
    'x': repo_names, # здесь без кавычек!
    'y': 'stars',
}]
```

Comment: 'ysxis': {'title': 'Stars'}, вот нашел ошибку!! по мимо этой !!

Comment: спасибо тебе! не первый раз помогаешь! я тебе благодарен!!